# features of resharper 6, absent completely or vastly improved upon from VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I've been using resharper for a long time now and I couldn't live without it, but I can't even tell anyone why really.  I've noticed when working on other developers' machines that often the features I use most exist in VS, albeit in a different place.  That said, perhaps the features are coming in from other add-ins and such, but the question remains

Basically I am looking for the broad stroke features of resharper that would convince a manager or director to purchase a site license.  As the title mentions, I am looking to avoid features that are mild improvements or duplicated features of vs2010.

Thanks

Comment: This question is actually *on topic* according to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "software tools commonly used by programmers" ... if voting to close, pick another category :)

Comment: Yeah, what pst said.  I can't imagine using Visual Studio without ReSharper.  It's a must-have programming tool for .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [comparison of Resharper 5 to Visual Studio 2010](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R5.html) on the Jetbrains website.

Comment: Pay special attention to the refactoring support.  It's worth the license fee even if that was all you get.

Comment: Piers, that was pretty much what I was looking for although version 6 should have some other things, but good enough.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper is so full of features that it's hard to say which are the mild improvements and which are deal breakers. Still, my list is:

1. Features that make it easy to learn new code: value origin/destination, incoming/outgoing calls and different navigations. They are really time-savers when you need to change other people code.
2. Features that makes it easy to write new code: various context actions for code generation and quick fixes for code corrections.
3. Refactorings. Although Visual Studio may have some of the refactorings, still ReSharper has more (and really useful, like Pull members up) and those that are duplicates are more refined.
4. Razor (if you use it). Visual Studio has few build-in features for it in comparison with C#. ReSharper has full support for most of C# features and several Razor-specific features.

Answer (score 1):

For the absolute bird's eye view of ReSharper you could do worse than show [this screencast](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/what-is-resharper). There is also [another screencast](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/whats-new-in-resharper-6) demonstrating the new features in ReSharper 6. Finally, if it's static content you're after, check out [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/DmitriNesteruk/resharper-presentation-for-nugs).